# Azure APIM -old developer portal not waiting more than a minute and its stopped

Tags: azure-api-management

We have a backend webservice which takes more than 1 minute to send response to the requester. APIM has configured to send requests to the backend service thru API. I have set forward request policy for this api to extend timeout settings to 180 secs. When I try this api with postman I'm getting response in 1 min 36 ms. and timeout works fine. But when I try with developer portal, request getting stopped exactly in 1 min and its not showing any response(its blank). How to increase this duration in old developer portal to wait response from backend service more than a minute.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to some research, it seems there is no way to increase the timeout in developer portal. It works in postman because we can configure timeout in postman like below screenshot:
[image]

As postman can meet your requirement, I think you can test the api in postman easily. If you still want to test in developer portal, you can raise a ticket on [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management) page to ask azure develop team add this feature.